# how to create Tag Cloud in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

How to create tag cloud in sharepoint2007. Is there any default designed tag cloud templates etc in Sharepoint2007?I want to show all the list items in a Tag cloud based on an integer value of that item. How to do this in Sharepoint?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Nuage - Tag cloud for Sharepoint](http://nuage.codeplex.com/)

> Nuage is a SharePoint solution which makes possible to tag items and display the tag cloud.
>
> Features:
>
> - The "Tags" column can be added on any list (including document libraries) by site administrators
> - Items can have an illimited number of tags
> - Users can tag any elements in these lists
> - The tag cloud shows all tags used in the site collection

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid thier is no default template template available in MOSS 2007 you can use the same from [WSSSearch](http://wsssearch.com/tagging.html)