# how to implement tag cloud in sharepoint 2007?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, tag-cloud

i want to implement tag cloud in sharepoint 2007. I want to enter data dynamically to the inputs of the tag cloud.

Comment: Please dont post exact duplicates - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182891/how-to-create-tag-cloud-in-sharepoint

Answer (score 0):

You can create a web part which renders the tag cloud by pulling data (tags) from a SharePoint list. You can have a column 'count' in the list based on which you can assign font size for the tags. I've created a similar kind of thing using asp repeater.

Comment: can you please provide more details regarding this one, as am i new to this

Comment: You can download this and check the code http://nuage.codeplex.com/. If you know how to create a custom web part and working with lists (creating/reading/updating items) you should be able to create the web part easily. But if you don't know developing a custom web part i strongly recommend to get comfortable with that before trying this.